# Sorting by size

Tags: command, sort

When I run

`ls | sort -S`

I get

`sort : option requires an argument -- ´S´`

Why I can't sort the list of my files with the sort option by size? I know that I can use only the `ls` command alone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all command **`ls`** has option `-S`

From `man ls`

```
-S     sort by file size
```

**So proper command is:**

```
ls -S
```

---

#### **`sort`** command is for sorting lines of text file:

From `man sort`:

```
-S, --buffer-size=SIZE
              use SIZE for main memory buffer
```

> SIZE is an integer and optional unit (example: 10M is 10*1024*1024).
>       Units are K, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y (powers of 1024) or KB, MB, ... (powers of 1000).

That's why you are getting error: `sort : option requires an argument -- ´S´`. Use **`ls -S`** for sorting file by size!

Comment: What is `100`? What does it mean? 100 kb?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still dont understand how it sort. If I take 100K then it will sort... how? The first is going to be the biggest file?

Comment: @c023 Have you noted that is for [memory buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) not for file size?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `du` command with some arguments and use `sort`

I use the following:

```
$ du -hsc /path/to/file
```

From `man du`

```
-h, --human-readable
      print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
-s, --summarize
      display only a total for each argument

-c, --total (I USE IT FOR EXTRA INFO)
      produce a grand total
```

To sort

```
$ du -hsc /path/to/file | sort -h
```

From `man sort`

```
-h, --human-numeric-sort
      compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
```